# Can rss feed be considered as web service

Tags: web-services, rss

I am currently learning about web service.

The zest is,
It gives output as XML.
Can be used to interact between two servers.

So my question is can RSS and Atom feeds be considered as web service. If not, then why?

Answer (score 1):

the simple answer is no. Because web service needs a service, just involving XML does not make it a web service. With experience you will understand.

Answer (score 1):

As @a. sam said, web service is a concept. We have to built build programs which is on java or asp.net which communicates with one another. RSS/ATOM is one way only is a source of data not a service.